# Limiting the input for all the textboxes to 2 digits(0-99), whose ID contains a certain text or has specific class. (jQuery)

Tags: jquery

I have two sets of textboxes which are generated dynamically. All these textboxes has either (`**textnormal**` or `**textnormalHS**`) as **class name** and all of them have a specific text ("txtMem") as part of their **ID**.
I want to limit the no of characters to be displayed in the texbox to 2.

```
$("input[type='text'][id*='txtMem']").keyup(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.val().length > 2) $this.val($this.val().substr(0, 2));
});
```

doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set the `maxlength` attribute to 2 for all those textboxes you don't need any JavaScript or jQuery for that.

```
<input type="text" maxlength="2" />
```

> The maxlength attribute specifies the maximum number of characters
>   allowed in the `<input>` element.

If you want to set it programmatically you can try this.

```
$("input:text[id*='txtMem']").attr('maxlength', 2);
```

Note that I am using `input:text` which is similar to `input[type='text']` but it is simple.